# mediaelement.js Getting (browser independent) errors in JS console

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I'm getting the following errors in different browsers. It seems to concern all the same problem of missing 'loaded' or 'width' object on line 1663 of mediaelement-and-player.js:

```
// update loaded bar
t.loaded.width(t.total.width() * percent);
```

(mediaelement.js Version 2.1.5)

It always occurs twice, once on the page loaded and once at the end of the played video.

IE9:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value
> of the property 'width': object is
> null or undefined
> mediaelement-and-player.js, line 1663
> character 4

FF4.01:

> t.loaded is undefined
> mediaelement-and-player.js
> Line 1663

Chrome 12:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'width' of undefined
> MediaElementPlayer.setProgressRailmediaelement-and-player.js:1663
> mejs.MediaElementPlayer.setControlsSizemediaelement-and-player.js:1328
> mejs.MediaElementPlayer.meReadymediaelement-and-player.js:1262
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'width' of undefined
> MediaElementPlayer.setProgressRailmediaelement-and-player.js:1663
> mejs.MediaElementPlayer.meReadymediaelement-and-player.js:1242